# How do I sign a TransactionHex with SeedHex using secp256k1 in C# with Bouncy Castle?

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, cryptocurrency, secp256k1

I have this nodejs snippet which I want to implement in C#.
The SignTransaction function takes in a seedHex string (length: 64) and a TransactionHex string, a signature is created using secp256k1 algorithm and appended to the end of the TransactionHex.

```js
const sha256 = require('sha256');
const EC = require('elliptic').ec;
const ec = new EC("secp256k1");

// Serialize a number into an 8-byte array. This is a copy/paste primitive, not worth
// getting into the details.
function uvarint64ToBuf (uint) {
    const result = [];

    while (uint >= 0x80) {
        result.push((uint & 0xFF) | 0x80);
        uint >>>= 7;
    }

    result.push(uint | 0);

    return new Buffer(result);
}

// Sign transaction with seed
function signTransaction (seed, txnHex) {
    const privateKey = ec.keyFromPrivate(seed);
    const transactionBytes = new Buffer(txnHex, 'hex');
    const transactionHash = new Buffer(sha256.x2(transactionBytes), 'hex');
    const signature = privateKey.sign(transactionHash);
    const signatureBytes = new Buffer(signature.toDER());
    const signatureLength = uvarint64ToBuf(signatureBytes.length);
    const signedTransactionBytes = Buffer.concat([
        transactionBytes.slice(0, -1),
        signatureLength,
        signatureBytes
    ])
    return signedTransactionBytes.toString('hex');
}
```

example transaction hex

```
01efa5060f5fdae5ed9d90e5f076b2c328a64e347d0c87e8e3317daec5a44fe7c8000102bd53e48625f49e60ff6b7a934e3871b54cc2a93a8737352e8320549e42e2322bab0405270000167b22426f6479223a2248656c6c6f20576f726c64227de807d461f4df9efad8a0f3f716002102bd53e48625f49e60ff6b7a934e3871b54cc2a93a8737352e8320549e42e2322b0000
```

example signed transaction hex returned from the javascript function

```
01efa5060f5fdae5ed9d90e5f076b2c328a64e347d0c87e8e3317daec5a44fe7c8000102bd53e48625f49e60ff6b7a934e3871b54cc2a93a8737352e8320549e42e2322bab0405270000167b22426f6479223a2248656c6c6f20576f726c64227de807d461f4df9efad8a0f3f716002102bd53e48625f49e60ff6b7a934e3871b54cc2a93a8737352e8320549e42e2322b00473045022100c36e2b80f2160304cf640b1296244e7a3873aacf2831098bca3727ad06f4c270022007d3697ceef266a05ad70219d92fbd570f6ec7a5731aaf02718213067d42d1cf
```

If you notice the signed hex is `TransactionHex + 47 (length of signature) + 473045022100c36e2b80f2160304cf640b1296244e7a3873aacf2831098bca3727ad06f4c270022007d3697ceef266a05ad70219d92fbd570f6ec7a5731aaf02718213067d42d1cf (actual signature)`

I am trying to use C# Bouncy Castle library in Unity3d to generate the signature part but no success.

This is the C# code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889096/c-sharp-sign-data-with-sha-256withecdsa-using-bouncycastle-produce-different-sig))

```cs
public string GetSignature(string privateKey, string message)
    {
        var curve = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256k1");
        var domain = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H);
        var keyParameters = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(new BigInteger(privateKey, 16), domain);

        var signer = new ECDsaSigner(new HMacDsaKCalculator(new Sha256Digest()));
        signer.Init(true, keyParameters);

        var signature = signer.GenerateSignature(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));

        var r = signature[0];
        var s = signature[1];

        var otherS = curve.Curve.Order.Subtract(s);

        if (s.CompareTo(otherS) == 1)
        {
            s = otherS;
        }

        var derSignature = new DerSequence
        (
            new DerInteger(new BigInteger(1, r.ToByteArray())),
            new DerInteger(new BigInteger(1, s.ToByteArray()))
        )
        .GetDerEncoded();

        return Convert(derSignature);
    }

    public string Convert(byte[] input)
    {
        return string.Concat(input.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
    }

    public byte[] Convert(string input)
    {
        if (input.StartsWith("0x")) input = input.Remove(0, 2);

        return Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length / 2).Select(x => System.Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)).ToArray();
    }
```

This does generate a signature but it is not identical to the one I mentioned above.

Signature generated from `GetSignature`

```
3044022018a06b1f2b8a1e2f5ea2a78b0d6d98ec483b9fa4345821cfef892be6c825ff4702207958160e533c801dff5e50600206e1cd938d6df74ebfa4b0347a95de67dda986
```

P.S. [Here](https://github.com/AdityaChaudhary0005/DeSo.py/blob/master/deso/Sign.py) is the python equivalent of signing transactions for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sha256.x2()` in the NodeJS code hashes twice, while `ECDsaSigner` in the C# code does not hash at all. Therefore, in the C# code, `GetSignature()` must explicitly hash twice:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;
...
var messageBytes = Convert(message);
var hash = GetHash(GetHash(messageBytes));
var signature = signer.GenerateSignature(hash);
...
```

with

```cs
private static byte[] GetHash(byte[] data)
{
    var digest = new Sha256Digest();
    var hash = new byte[digest.GetDigestSize()];
    digest.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length);
    digest.DoFinal(hash, 0);
    return hash;
}
```

Since both codes use the deterministic ECDSA algorithm according to RFC6979, the hashes for the same input data are identical and can be compared.

The overall result is the concatenation of `txnHex` without the last byte, the hex encoded length of the signature and the signature in ASN.1/DER format; a possible implementation is:

```cs
var txnHex = "...";
var seed = "...";
string signature = GetSignature(seed, txnHex);
string signedTransactionBytes = txnHex.Substring(0, txnHex.Length - 2) + (signature.Length / 2).ToString("x") + signature;
```

Note that the `uvarint64ToBuf()` implementation is actually more complex, but can be simplified for the signature lengths used here.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know where I was going wrong and it works perfectly :))